# jquery-mobile spinner loading

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i tried to do that while js is creating a timetable... it shows spinner loading..

i tried to do this `$.mobile.pageLoading();    $.mobile.pageLoading(true);`   and also tried to use this plugin http://contextllc.com/tools/jQuery-showLoading

The result is the same.. it shows spinner after he generate time table.. and i don't know why...here is where i tried to use it...

```
                    $('#timeDropList').change(function() {

                        $.mobile.pageLoading(false);
                        $('div.addedEntry').remove();
                        drawTemplate();

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right version of jQuery Mobile? Looks like they took away the `pageLoading` method in 1.0b1 in favor of two separate methods: `showPageLoadingMsg` and `hidePageLoadingMsg`. The last reference I see to `pageLoading` is in 1.0a4.1.

Comment: yeah i use 1.0a4.1.. i tried to use newer version.. but my application failed to load...

Comment: when i try to use new version... it doesn't show error or something.. it begin to load and then goes white screen...

Comment: get this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery16204975308058783412' of undefined -- From line 133 of file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js

Comment: okey.. i update jq-m version to the latest one.. but the question i asked still aren't solved..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#home').live('pagebeforecreate',function(event){
      alert('This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!');
      $.mobile.loadingMessage = "pagebeforeshow Page...";
      $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    });
```